# Lead Conversion Issue : Specified Contact must be parented by specified Account: []

Tags: lead-conversion

I am trying to convert Lead through leadConvert class but getting error like this " System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, Specified Contact must be parented by specified Account: []"

Can anyone please help?

Here is my code::

---

```
        List<Database.LeadConvert> leadToconvert = New List<Database.LeadConvert>();
        for(Lead l: ld){
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();

            lc.setLeadId(l.id);
            System.debug('lc.setLeadId(l.id);' + l.id);
            System.debug('l.Company::' +l.Company);
            lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus);
            System.debug('(lacc.get(0).Id)::::' +lacc.get(0).Id +'--'+lacc.get(0).name );
            lc.setAccountId(lacc.get(0).Id);

            System.debug('getaccountid :: '+ lc.getAccountId());
            if(flag == '1'){
                System.debug('lc.setContactId(lcon.get(0).id)::::' + lcon.get(0).id +'--'+lcon.get(0).name);
                lc.setContactId(lcon.get(0).id);
            }

            leadToconvert.add(lc);
            System.debug('leadToconvert' + leadToconvert);
        }
        List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(leadToconvert);
```

Comment: What do your debug statement outputs look like? In particular, the one that's outputting lacc.get(0).Id

Comment: Have you seen this?  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008sCYIAY

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid this error you could try the following:
please check "Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts" in "Account Settings".

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by setting additional condition for company and its related contact.

Answer (score 0):

I like Pavlo's suggestion of checking the 'multiple accounts' checkbox in the Account settings. With luck Lead conversion should take account of this.

Alternatively, the classic, though long winded approach is to define a custom Account lookup field ('Target Site') on the Lead and Opportunity records, set the field mapping from one to the other in the Lead's field mappings and then build a Create Opportunity trigger to amend the Opportunity's AccountId field on creation to use the Target Site value. This worked for me and is something of a standard pattern for these kind of issues (eg setting the record type of the opp according to some Lead field).